# Is there a best practice to configure private VPC to access S3 bucket?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-vpc

I created a VPC for my Elastic Beanstalk in China. The service delivers files from an S3 bucket located in the same region in China (cn-north-1). If the same service is running in the AWS Default VPC, I have access times of 1 to 2 seconds, but the same service in the VPC always takes 3 to 5 seconds. Do I have to pay attention to anything with the VPC?

Comment: Some relevant parts of the infrastructure would be: DNS Servers, Firewall/Gateways.  Is the routing out of your non-default VPC the same as your default VPC?  If not, are you using all AWS products (Nat Gateway, AWS provided DNS) or something else?

Comment: @erik258 I use only AWS products. "Is the routing out of your non-default VPC the same as your default VPC?" is there any guide which I can follow? During my research I found more than one times a specific endpoint configuration to access the S3 bucket but I didn't quite understand that.

Comment: My EC2 instances run in a private subnet where the outgoing traffic go through a NAT Gateway, do you think that a specific endpoint configuration to S3 beside the NAT Gateway is a better approach?

Answer (score 0):

To access S3 from your VPC, it is better to use endpoint,  which will use private IP addresses to access Amazon S3 with no exposure to the public internet, thus all communications between your VPC and S3 will be via AWS backbone instead of via internet.  This will also save some cost as well.